# How to start, stop and reset the chronometer in android?

Tags: android, chronometer

How to set start , stop , reset in chronometer ?

I'm implementing chronometer in my app. I created three buttons
start, stop , reset..
start : starts timer from the 00:00.
stop: completely stops timer showing the time runned.
reset: resets the timer to 00:00.

i'm trying to do this but my code behaves weird.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
}
public void startButton(View view) {
    ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer)).start();
}  


public void stopButton(View view) {
    ((Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.chronometer)).stop();
}
public void resetButton(View view) {
    ((Chronometer) 
findViewById(R.id.chronometer)).setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
}}
```

how can i solve this problem?
i just want to implement a start button(starts form 00:00) , stop button(stops the timer and shows runned time) and a reset button(which completely resets the timer to 00:00).

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
    import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.Chronometer;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Chronometer simpleChronometer;
    Button start, stop, restart, setFormat, clearFormat;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        // initiate views
        simpleChronometer = (Chronometer) findViewById(R.id.simpleChronometer);
        start = (Button) findViewById(R.id.startButton);
        stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
        restart = (Button) findViewById(R.id.restartButton);
        setFormat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.setFormat);
        clearFormat = (Button) findViewById(R.id.clearFormat);
        // perform click  event on start button to start a chronometer
        start.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                simpleChronometer.start();
            }
        });

        // perform click  event on stop button to stop the chronometer
        stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                simpleChronometer.stop();
            }
        });

        // perform click  event on restart button to set the base time on chronometer
        restart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                simpleChronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            }
        });

        // perform click  event on set Format button to set the format of chronometer
        setFormat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                simpleChronometer.setFormat("Time (%s)");
            }
        });

        // perform click  event on clear button to clear the current format of chronmeter as you set through set format
        clearFormat.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                simpleChronometer.setFormat(null);
            }
        });
    }


}
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The code works fine but i want to implement reset instead of restart..

Comment: i want to use only three buttons one to start timer from exactly 00:00, one to stop the timer and another one to reset(not restart) the timer from 00:00. in simple words i need to use simple stopwatch just like in our android phones.

Answer (score 0):

I know it may be the little late, this can help someone later on

```
stop = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopButton);
chronometer = findViewById(R.id.chronometerID);

stop.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                 chronometer.stop();
                 chronometer.setBase(SystemClock.elapsedRealtime());
            }
        });
```